# IQueryable throws OutOfMemory exception with Where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, breeze, asp.net-web-api2, iqueryable

UPDATE : 09/03/15

Ok, I tried to do a .Join instead:

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<RunOfferPublish> RunOfferPublishes()
    {
        var showIds = _showSecurityCache.GetRunIdsForCurrentUser().AsEnumerable();
        return Context.RunOfferPublishes.Join(showIds, r => r.RunOffer.Run.showId, i => i, (r, i) => r);
    }
```

I get another exception saying that my query is nested to deep. I made a method to reduce the nesting and get the runIds instead. However, there's much more ids..

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<RunOfferPublish> RunOfferPublishes()
    {
        var runIds = _showSecurityCache.GetRunIdsForCurrentUser().AsEnumerable();
        return Context.RunOfferPublishes.Join(runIds, r => r.RunOffer.RunId, i => i, (r, i) => r);
    }
```

I get a stackoverflow exception, there's to much runs.

Then I tried to remove get a liste of all the entities, and do the where in memory. Like this:

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<RunOfferPublish> RunOfferPublishes()
    {
        var showIds = _showSecurityCache.GetShowIdsForCurrentUser();
        var list = Context.RunOfferPublishes.ToList();
        return list.Where(i => showIds.Contains(i.RunOffer.Run.ShowId)).AsQueryable();
    }
```

This "works", it returns the list of entities. However, I get an issue with Breeze

> 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery' does not contain a definition for 'Include'

```
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String )
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String )
at Breeze.WebApi.QueryHelper.<>c__DisplayClass14.<ApplyExpand>b__11(String expand)
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
at Breeze.WebApi.QueryHelper.ApplyExpand(IQueryable queryable, String expandsQueryString)
at Breeze.WebApi.QueryHelper.ApplySelectAndExpand(IQueryable queryable, NameValueCollection map)
at Breeze.WebApi.BreezeQueryableAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.CallOnActionExecuted(HttpActionContext actionContext, HttpResponseMessage response, Exception exception)
at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<>c__DisplayClass2.<System.Web.Http.Filters.IActionFilter.ExecuteActionFilterAsync>b__0(HttpResponseMessage response)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass41`2.<Then>b__40(Task`1 t)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThenImpl[TTask,TOuterResult](TTask task, Func`2 continuation, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean runSynchronously)
```

Thus, I'm still stuck.

----- Issue Update Above ----

I'm trying to investigate an issue with this controller method:

```
        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<RunOfferPublish> RunOfferPublishes()
        {
        var showIds = _showSecurityCache.GetShowIdsForCurrentUser();
        var query = Context.RunOfferPublishes.Where(rop => showIds.Contains(rop.RunOffer.Run.ShowId)).AsQueryable();
        return query;
    }
```

The showIds array is a list of 212 small integers (0 to 212).
The RunOfferPublishes is a table in the DBContext (Context)

If I removed the .Where the query is working but it throws an outof memory exception with it. I tried to see what the generated SQL was but I believe it does not reach this point because I don't see it through the SQL Profiler.

The exception :

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'  was thrown.
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.EnsureCapacity(Int32 min)
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitBinaryJoin(Node joinNode, DbExpressionKind joinKind)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.Visit(LeftOuterJoinOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.LeftOuterJoinOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitAsRelOp(Node inputNode)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitJoinInput(Node joinInputNode)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitBinaryJoin(Node joinNode, DbExpressionKind joinKind)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.Visit(LeftOuterJoinOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.LeftOuterJoinOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitAsRelOp(Node inputNode)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitJoinInput(Node joinInputNode)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitBinaryJoin(Node joinNode, DbExpressionKind joinKind)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.Visit(LeftOuterJoinOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.LeftOuterJoinOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitAsRelOp(Node inputNode)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitJoinInput(Node joinInputNode)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitBinaryJoin(Node joinNode, DbExpressionKind joinKind)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.Visit(LeftOuterJoinOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.LeftOuterJoinOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitAsRelOp(Node inputNode)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitJoinInput(Node joinInputNode)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitBinaryJoin(Node joinNode, DbExpressionKind joinKind)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.Visit(LeftOuterJoinOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.LeftOuterJoinOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitAsRelOp(Node inputNode)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitJoinInput(Node joinInputNode)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitBinaryJoin(Node joinNode, DbExpressionKind joinKind)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.Visit(LeftOuterJoinOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.LeftOuterJoinOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitAsRelOp(Node inputNode)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitJoinInput(Node joinInputNode)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitBinaryJoin(Node joinNode, DbExpressionKind joinKind)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.Visit(LeftOuterJoinOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.LeftOuterJoinOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitAsRelOp(Node inputNode)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.Visit(FilterOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.FilterOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitAsRelOp(Node inputNode)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.BuildProjection(Node relOpNode, IEnumerable`1 projectionVars)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.Visit(PhysicalProjectOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.PhysicalProjectOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator..ctor(Command itree, Node toConvert)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.ProviderCommandInfoUtils.Create(Command command, Node node, List`1 children)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.CodeGen.Process(List`1& childCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount)
at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler.Compile(List`1& providerCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount, Set`1& entitySets)
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree)
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree)
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree)
 at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree)
 at  System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Span span, ReadOnlyCollection`1 compiledQueryParameters, AliasGenerator aliasGenerator)
 at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
 at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery.ToTraceString()
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1.ToString()
 at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.ToString()
 at ******************MainController.RunOfferPublishes() in
```

Comment: It looks as if you're traversing three tables to see if an ID is contained on what could potentially be a large collection and, even worse, it looks like you're doing it in memory.  I'm guessing that's your issue.

Comment: Are you sure it's only 212 integers? Can you change it to this: `var showIds = _showSecurityCache.GetShowIdsForCurrentUser().ToList()` and verify that? Does it still give you an OOM exception when using the `ToList` form?

Comment: @Rob Yes I'm, I debugged that part. GetShowIdsForCurrentUser() returns a list.

Comment: @DavidL Could that be it? The first 2 tables have around 5k records, the third and last tables less than 1k.

Comment: Anything is possible depending on how your tables are configured.  You haven't been able to post a query so your guess is definitely better than mine :)

Comment: What happens if you don't call `AsQueryable()` and you instead call `ToList()`?

Comment: I disagree that it's doing the join in memory - the stack trace is from building the SQL. It fails on this: `System.Collections.Generic.List1.set_Capacity(Int32 value)` - which is from calling `AddRange()` on a list. Now, either your list has a huge amount of values (which you've confirmed doesn't), or your machine is starved of memory already. It also seems fishy that a controller method returns an `IQueryable`. Can you change the method to return `IList<RunOfferPublish>`, and change `AsQueryable()` to `ToList()`?

Comment: @DavidL Same error using ToList, it takes forever and I get the OutOfMemory exception.

Comment: @Rob It's returning an IQueryable to fit with Breeze, that's normal. I agree that it must be failing when building the SQL, that's why I can't see the generated SQL in the profiler.

Comment: This looks like an EF bug. Excessive memory consumption or even an infinite loop.

Comment: @usr I disagree with your conclusion that it's an EF bug.  It's possible that there's a bad data relationship which is leading to infinite joiner table traversal, but without more context here it's impossible to say.  However, to jump straight to EF bug seems a bit farfetched.

Comment: @Machinegon why it would it return an IQueryable so that Breeze can consume it?  Won't your API serialize it to json either way?  At that point Breeze will have absolutely no idea whether or not it's an IQuerable or IList since the collection type will no longer exist.

Comment: @DavidL what do you mean by bad data relationship? Not detecting a bad schema (if you mean that) is a bug as well.

Comment: Using a large local collection with `Contains` in the query like this should always be avoided. If you cannot do it another way then your database is wrong designed. I think this is a problem on database side not on client side. Think about the similar SQL query where u can insert **hardcoded-values** (~ 213 values) to check against each record (and you may have thousands or even millions of records)? U can try reducing the number of elements in the local collection and run it until it succeeds to view the SQL query.From that u can copy the query, modify it with larger set and try it directly.

Comment: @Hopeless the database was not called at the point of the exception. It can't be a server-side problem.

Comment: @usr from the stacktrace it seems like that, I'm not sure but EF may be designed to detect the limited capability of data provider beforehand and throws the exception on its behalf.

Comment: @Hopeless this is not a controlled exception. It's a crash. 2GB+ memory usage is not expected from EF query compilation code. This is a bug.

Comment: @DavidL There's foreign-key relationships between RunOfferPubish, RunOffer and run. I agree that the database is not designed to do this, this security filtering was requested after the database was first implemented. However, it should still run.

Comment: Could you try to do this with a small number of integers and check the generated query? Is seems that EF chokes in the number of joins it's trying to generate. But that's weird, because `Contains` should be translated into an `IN` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a join this way, solves the problem. It's like you have to tell EF exactly what SQL to generate otherwise it crashes.

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<RunOfferPublish> RunOfferPublishes()
    {
        var showIds = _showSecurityCache.GetShowIdsForCurrentUser();
        return (from rop in Context.RunOfferPublishes
                   join ro in Context.RunOffers on rop.RunOfferId equals ro.RunOfferId
                   join r in Context.Runs on ro.RunId equals r.RunId
                   where showIds.Contains(r.ShowId)
                   select rop);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an issue with older versions of EF. I tried this with EF 4.1 and 6.1.3. In 4.1,  with **only 3 items (!)** in the list, the query structure is like this:

```sql
SELECT 
[Extent1].[AId] AS [AId], 
[Extent1].[BId] AS [BId], 
...
FROM         [dbo].[A] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[B] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[BId] = [Extent2].[BId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[C] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[CId] = [Extent3].[CId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[B] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent1].[BId] = [Extent4].[BId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[C] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent4].[CId] = [Extent5].[CId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[C] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent4].[CId] = [Extent6].[CId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[C] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent4].[CId] = [Extent7].[CId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[C] AS [Extent8] ON [Extent4].[CId] = [Extent8].[CId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[C] AS [Extent9] ON [Extent4].[CId] = [Extent9].[CId]
WHERE (1 = (CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[DId] IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE [Extent5].[DId] END)) 
   OR (2 = (CASE WHEN ([Extent6].[DId] IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE [Extent7].[DId] END)) 
   OR (3 = (CASE WHEN ([Extent8].[DId] IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE [Extent9].[DId] END))
```

So clearly with a larger number of items the number of joins to be generated outgrows available resources.

You didn't tell which EF version you use, but I wouldn't be surprised if closer research would turn out that this query shape was like this until recent considerable **query generation improvements** in versions since 6.1. In 6.1.3 the query shape is as expected:

```sql
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[AId] AS [AId], 
    [Extent1].[BId] AS [BId], 
    ...
    FROM   [dbo].[A] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[B] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[BId] = [Extent2].[BId]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[C] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[CId] = [Extent3].[CId]
    WHERE (CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[DId] IS NULL) THEN 0 
    ELSE [Extent3].[DId] END IN (1, 2, 3)) 
    AND (CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[DId] IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE [Extent3].[DId] END IS NOT NULL)
```

And with `context.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;` even slimmer:

```sql
WHERE CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[DId] IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE [Extent3].[DId] END IN (1, 2, 3)
```

So you can either use the work-around you managed to find, or upgrade to a later EF version.

Answer (score 0):

EF and Contains often don't play well together. Mabe it's possible to rewrite the query without the contains. I'm guessing at your DB schema, but maybe something along these lines:

```
var userId = _showSecurityCache.GetIdForCurrentUser();
var query = Context.RunOfferPublishes.Where(rop => Context.Users.Any(u => u.Id == userId && u.Shows.Any(s => s.Id == rop.RunOffer.Run.ShowId))).AsQueryable();
return query;
```

Comment: That won't work, the access is entity based that's why I'm retreiving the the shows that the user has acces to. Than I'm filtering the query on that to make sure the user does not see the entities related to other shows.

Comment: My example filters on the shows a user has access to also (the u.Shows.Any bit). But my solution does require the user and his shows to be in the same DBContext as the RunOfferPublishers. I can't tell if that is the case or if you can access a users shows via the user.